# How to join info from two tables in SQL query?

Tags: sql

I'd like to write a SQL query to join information from two tables in order to populate a struct.

My first table contains the metadata about the groups:

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| GroupID | String |
| DisplayName | String |
| CreateTime | String |

My second table contains the group members:

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| PersonID | String |
| GroupID | String |

I would like to read rows for all groups created in a given time interval (i.e. `WHERE r.CreateTime >= start_time AND r.CreateTime < end_time`) and then get the PersonIDs belonging to that group. Eventually, I'd like to populate a struct that looks as follows:

```
struct GroupInfo {
    string groupID;
    string groupName;
    vector<string> groupMemberIDs;
}
```

I am stuck on how to write the SQL query for this type of problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which database system are you using? try JOIN the tables and apply your time selection

Comment: Please share the RDBMS you are using. Each one differs on the few features you can use to do this type of groupMember string/structure aggregation (listagg/stringagg or json functionality). Can you clarify what you mean by `struct` as well? Is it like the JSON concept where your output for a single row would be `{"groupID":"1","groupName":"penguins", "groupMemberIDs":[1,2,3,4,5]}` ? Sample data and desired results would help us understand.

Comment: Why is `CreateTime` a string? This doesn't seem to make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of JOIN, WHERE, and GROUP_CONCAT (or STRING_AGG depending on your SQL database) functions. Here's a sample SQL query that should help you get the desired result:

```sql
SELECT
    g.GroupID AS groupID,
    g.DisplayName AS groupName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(m.PersonID) AS groupMemberIDs
FROM
    GroupsTable g
JOIN
    GroupMembersTable m ON g.GroupID = m.GroupID
WHERE
    g.CreateTime >= start_time AND g.CreateTime < end_time
GROUP BY
    g.GroupID, g.DisplayName;
```

1. The query uses a JOIN operation to combine information from the **GroupsTable** (aliased as **g**) and the **GroupMembersTable** (aliased as **m**) based on the common column **GroupID**.
2. The WHERE clause filters the results to include only rows where the group creation time is within the specified time interval.
3. The SELECT clause extracts the necessary information: **GroupID** and **DisplayName** from the **GroupsTable**, and it uses the GROUP_CONCAT function to concatenate the **PersonID** values into a comma-separated list for each group.
4. Finally, the GROUP BY clause groups the results by **GroupID** and **DisplayName**.

Make sure to replace **GroupsTable** and **GroupMembersTable** with the actual names of your tables, and adjust the column names accordingly based on your schema.

**Note:** The exact SQL syntax might vary slightly depending on the specific database system you are using (e.g., MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server), so make sure to check the documentation for your specific database.

Running a query returns (random data):

**GroupsTable:**

```yaml
| GroupID | DisplayName | CreateTime           |
|---------|-------------|----------------------|
| G1      | Group1      | 2023-01-01 10:00:00  |
| G2      | Group2      | 2023-01-02 12:30:00  |
| G3      | Group3      | 2023-01-03 15:45:00  |
| G4      | Group4      | 2023-01-04 08:00:00  |
```

**GroupMembersTable:**

```yaml
| PersonID | GroupID |
|----------|---------|
| P1       | G1      |
| P2       | G1      |
| P3       | G2      |
| P4       | G2      |
| P5       | G3      |
| P6       | G4      |
| P7       | G4      |
```

**Query Results:**

```
| groupID | groupName | groupMemberIDs    |
|---------|-----------|-------------------|
| G1      | Group1    | P1,P2             |
| G2      | Group2    | P3,P4             |
| G3      | Group3    | P5                |
| G4      | Group4    | P6,P7             |
```

Assuming you want a c++ code to connect to database, run query and populate the structure. You would use something in the lines of next code snippet:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sql_database_library>  // Replace with the actual library you are using

struct GroupInfo {
    std::string groupID;
    std::string groupName;
    std::vector<std::string> groupMemberIDs;
};

int main() {
    // Replace with your actual database connection code
    // For example, in a C++ program using SQLite:
    // SQLiteConnection connection("your_database.db");
    // connection.open();

    // Replace with the actual SQL query based on your database library
    std::string sqlQuery = "SELECT g.GroupID AS groupID, g.DisplayName AS groupName, GROUP_CONCAT(m.PersonID) AS groupMemberIDs "
                           "FROM GroupsTable g "
                           "JOIN GroupMembersTable m ON g.GroupID = m.GroupID "
                           "WHERE g.CreateTime >= 'start_time' AND g.CreateTime < 'end_time' "
                           "GROUP BY g.GroupID, g.DisplayName";

    // Execute the query and fetch results
    // Replace with the actual code for executing the query in your database library
    // std::vector<GroupInfo> results = executeSqlQueryAndGetResults(connection, sqlQuery);

    // For demonstration purposes, let's simulate the results
    std::vector<GroupInfo> results = {
        {"G1", "Group1", {"P1", "P2"}},
        {"G2", "Group2", {"P3", "P4"}},
        {"G3", "Group3", {"P5"}},
        {"G4", "Group4", {"P6", "P7"}}
    };

    // Process the results
    for (const auto& result : results) {
        std::cout << "GroupID: " << result.groupID << std::endl;
        std::cout << "GroupName: " << result.groupName << std::endl;
        std::cout << "GroupMemberIDs: ";
        
        for (const auto& memberID : result.groupMemberIDs) {
            std::cout << memberID << ",";
        }

        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }

    // Close the database connection (if applicable)
    // connection.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that the code above is a template and may require modifications based on your specific programming language, database library, and other details. Replace the placeholder comments with the actual code relevant to your setup.

Answer (score 0):

For mysql

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `Groups` (
  `GroupID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `DisplayName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `CreateTime` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`GroupID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `PersonInGroup` (
  `GroupID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `PersonID` varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

Insert into `Groups` values ('0', 'blue', 'Today');
Insert into `Groups` values ('1', 'red', 'Today');

Insert into `PersonInGroup` values ('1', 'r1');
Insert into `PersonInGroup` values ('1', 'r2');

Insert into `PersonInGroup` values ('0', 'b1');
Insert into `PersonInGroup` values ('0', 'b2');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
Select Groups.*, JSON_ARRAYAGG(PersonInGroup.PersonID)
from Groups
left join PersonInGroup
    on Groups.GroupID = PersonInGroup.GroupID
where Groups.CreateTime = 'Today'
Group by Groups.GroupID;
```

| GroupID | DisplayName | CreateTime | JSON_ARRAYAGG(PersonInGroup.PersonID) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | blue | Today | ["b1", "b2"] |
| 1 | red | Today | ["r1", "r2"] |

---

**Query #2**

```
Select Groups.*,  Group_concat(PersonInGroup.PersonID)
from Groups
left join PersonInGroup
    on Groups.GroupID = PersonInGroup.GroupID
where Groups.CreateTime = 'Today'
Group by Groups.GroupID ;
```

| GroupID | DisplayName | CreateTime | Group_concat(PersonInGroup.PersonID) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | blue | Today | b1,b2 |
| 1 | red | Today | r2,r1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rsuZ5YLQa4TxmbpUFZx6J1/1)

And then parse JSON array or comma separated values string into vector.